# What is the difference between PKCS#7 and CADES, PADES and XADES?

Tags: digital-signature, pdf, pkcs7, eidas

I am newbie in PKI. For signing a pdf documents we are free to consider each pkcs#7 format or PADES format. If I have some misunderstandings, please turn it on for me.

Comment: I edited the question's tags, maybe someone knowledgeable in this will answer. Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_electronic_signature and things linked from there?

Comment: @Z.T Thank you for your guidance. but in practice, PKCS#7 can fulfills this requirement. i still don't understand the difference.

Answer (score 1):

A public key infrastructure (PKI) is a system for the creation, storage, and distribution of digital certificates (contains public key and owner's information signed by a trusted Certificate Authority like intesi).
While signing a document, the hash of the document generated using hashing algorithm is encrypted with a private key of the signer. While verifying the signature, this encrypted hash is decrypted using a public key from the digital certificate present in the signature.

Here Signature format specifies which hashing and encryption algorithm is used for signing and how and which other information needs to be added to signature for its validation and verification.

**PKCS7 or Cryptographic Message Syntax (CMS)**: PKCS7 is standard syntax for storing signed data. This contains certificate and revocation information(CRLs and OCSPs) along with the signed hash of the document.

CAdES (CMS Advanced Electronic Signatures) is a set of extensions to CMS making it suitable for advanced electronic signatures( has met the requirements set forth under [EU Regulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulation_(European_Union)) ).
The extensions to CMS are added either as authenticated attributes (those that are co-signed with the rest of the message) or unauthenticated attributes that are added after the signature.

XADES: Specifies a set of extensions that are used with the W3C recommendation for XML Signature Syntax and Processing.

**PADES (PDF Advanced Electronic Signatures)**:  PAdES is a set of restrictions and extensions to PDFs making it suitable for advanced electronic signatures. PAdES provides the same capabilities featured in CAdES and XAdES but can apply only to PDF documents and defines requirements that PDF viewing and editing software must follow when using digital signatures in PDF documents. In PADES, a signing certificate is also added to CMS as a signed attribute.

*PADES is the recommended signature format* because it is more strict and concrete while PKCS7 signature in that sense is more relaxed and its possible to change more things in PDF without invalidating digital signatures. PKCS7 is still supported for compatibility because many PDF viewers support this signature format.